# PhP Date Expire within Options

Tags: php, function, date

```
<?php
function saturday22march(){
if(date('d-m-Y') <= '11-01-2014'){
 echo '<option>saturday 22 march</option>';
}else{
echo '';
}
}
function friday16may(){
if(date('d-m-Y') <= '17-04-2014'){
 echo 'friday 16 may';
} else{
echo '';
}
}
$Content= '
<div class="content">
I am signing up for the following date:<br />
<select name="date[0]">
'. saturday22march();
   friday16may() .'
</select>
</div>
';
echo $Content;
?>
```

This is what I have. I want, for example, if it's March 23, that the `<options Saturday 22 march</option>` is no longer visible or available. How can I do this?

---

This is an other thing i tried to make it is the same but other wise made

```
function saturday22march(){
    $ret= "";
    if(time() <= strtotime('11-01-2014')){
     $ret =   'saturday 22 march';
    }
    return $ret;
}
function friday16mei(){
    $ret= "";
    if(time() <= strtotime('17-04-2014')){
     $ret =   'friday 16 mei';
    }
    return $ret;
}
function getoptions(){
    $ret = "";
    
    $saturday22 = saturday22march();
    if(strlen($saturday22) > 0){
        $ret = "<option>" . $saturday22 . "</option>";
    }
    
    $friday16mei = friday16mei();
    
    if(strlen($friday16mei) > 0){
        $ret = "<option>"    . $friday16mei . "</option>";
    }
    
    return $ret;
}
$Content= '
<div class="content">
    I am signing up for the following date:<br />
    <select name="date[0]">
        '. getoptions() .'
    </select>
</div>
';
echo $Content;
```

Comment: If you want to compare dates as strings, use `Y-m-d` format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert the other way around, strings are not good date representations, comparisions between them will not exploit true relations between dates (at least not in this ordering, as year should be the most important one). The more "proper" way is to compare the unix timestamps of given dates.

Instead of

```
if(date('d-m-Y') <= '11-01-2014'){
```

you should use

```
if(time() <= strtotime('11-01-2014')){
```

Comment: Okay okay but now my problem is how do i get those 2 in the select box? And how do i let them Expire? on date then because there is nothing showing up right now in the select box

Comment: It works just fine, i pasted your code (with my modification) to http://writecodeonline.com/php/ and it creates valid code (with one option). The only small error is that you do `$ret = "<option> ...` while it should be `$ret .= "<option>...` (otherwise it will never create 2 options).